# Unable to connect static UITableView cells to controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an iOS 7 app with a `UIViewController` that contains a several `UILabel`s and a `UITableView` with static cells. In the storyboard, I have connected the `UILabel`s and the details of the `UITableViewCell`s to outlets.

In the `viewDidLoad:` method, the `UILabel`s outside of the `UITableView` are connected and allow me to use them. However, I am finding that the outlets for the `UILabels` in the `UITableView` are set to `null`.

For example, I have control-dragged from my storyboard to the interface to set up two outlets, a title label and a category label. The former is outside the table, the latter is the detail of a "Left detail" styled table view cell. In my interface I have these:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;
```

In the `viewDidLoad:` the property titleLabel has a value. The categoryLabel is null. So when I am setting data, the title will get filled, but the category stays blank.

I've tried looking for similar issues, but all of the tableViews that I see are part of a `UITableViewController` and not part of a `UIViewController`. I am not getting any errors in the output. I tried recreating my window from scratch. Nothing seems to fix it.

Does anyone have an idea as to what is going on? Is there some tool that I can use to see what is happening when iOS is doing connections to outlets?

Comment: It used to be (in iOS 6) that you needed to use a UITableViewController for static table views. Do you know that this has changed? If not, that could be your problem.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense. Inconvenient though. But it would be nice to know that I should just stop trying to do what I'm doing. :-)
Is there anywhere where this is documented?

Comment: Not official documentation, but take a look at the class dump of `UITableViewController`: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITableViewController.h
It has a `staticDataSource` property of class `UITableViewDataSource `, but that property is only defined on `UITableViewController`.